# C How to convert ASCII numbers in an array to text

Tags: c, ascii

How do I convert this array with ASCII numbers to text, so every number get's a letter. So "72" gets H, 101 gets E and so on.

`int a[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100};`

Comment: It should be noted the answers so far assume the C implementation uses ASCII. This is common but not required by the C standard. If you want to print the characters of ASCII character codes in a C implementation that does not use ASCII, you must of course translate them to the native scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. C Character Type C uses char type to store characters and letters. However, the char type is integer type because underneath C stores integer numbers instead of characters.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char **env) {
    int a[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof(int); ++i) {
        printf("%c", (char) a[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast... it's not only redundant: it's a *pessimization*: after the 1st explicit conversion with the cast, the compiler will do another conversion to `int` for passing the value to the *variadic function*. `printf("%c", a[i]);` is perfectly ok: `"%c"` expects a value of type `int`.

Comment: Also, `(char)` could produce incorrect results (including behavior not defined by the C standard) if `char` were signed and the array included character codes outside the `char` range (which would also be beyond ASCII).

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the array, and use the `%c` formating parameter  to print the ascii characters of the int value

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 11; i ++){
   printf("%c", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea since this assumes little endian storage. On a big endian computer, all you'd print would be a bunch of symbol zero (non-printable).

Comment: Thankss, you really helped me out :D

Comment: @Lundin : no, there is no endianness involved here. The arrary-contents are evaluated as *values*, and these values are used as arguments for the printf().

Comment: I don't understand why endianness would be a problem, it only change when dealing with types larger than one byte. Here we want a mapping byte->character. It would be independent of endianness

Comment: Consider `printf("%c", (int){0x11223344});`. This prints `'D'` on my little endian machine, because 0x44 is the ASCII code for `'D'`. On a big endian machine it would have printed whatever gibberish `0x11` corresponds to. Similarly, `printf("%X", *(unsigned int*)(char[]){0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44});` prints `44332211`.

Comment: That is, the internal conversion of the va_list parameters inside printf is (correct me if I'm wrong) not guaranteed to be done by assignment conversion `some_char = the_passed_int;` but might as well be done through `*(char*)&the_passed_int`.

Comment: Well now I understand where the problem may be ! Do you think a simple cast like `printf("%c", (char)a[i])` would solve the problem ?

Comment: `c      If no l modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char,` <<-- printf() expects an int. And it will get one in both cases. (bare characters would be converted to int, when given to printf())

Comment: @wildplasser But it doesn't specify _how_ the conversion takes place. Both my examples in the last comment are conversions. Though come to think of it, this might be implicitly specified because of the "default argument promotions". So when you pass an actual `char`, printf doesn't get one, but always an `int`. Meaning that it couldn't do `*(char*)&the_passed_int` or that would break plain characters passed. Hmm okay so I might be wrong here.

Comment: Yes, character values are always promoted to int, even in the case of `for (cp="hello"; *cp; cp++) { printf("%d\n", *cp); }` (works for `"%c\n"`, too)

Comment: @Lundin: “This is a bad idea since this assumes little endian storage. On a big endian computer, all you'd print would be a bunch of symbol zero (non-printable)” is rubbish. Per C 2018 6.5.2.2 7, the default argument promotions are performed on the arguments after the format string, so both `a[i]` and `(char) a[i]` are passed in exactly the same way, as an `int` with the value of `a[i]` (unless one of the array elements is outside the range of `char`, which none in the question are).

Comment: @Lundin: Re “But it doesn't specify how the conversion takes place”: The conversion is performed according to C 2018 6.3.1.3. Clause 6.3 specifies behaviors of conversions that apply throughout the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in C is numbers. The compiler can't tell a difference between the integer constant `72` and `'H'`, either results in a number and they even both have the type `int`. Characters and number formats only apply when you present raw data to a human user.

So there's no converting `72` to `'H'`, it's already in the correct format, the raw number 72. We simply need to tell the computer that we want this raw number to get printed as a character. The simplest way is `printf("%c", ...` but that one expects a parameter of type `char`. So we would have to convert the `a[0]` from `int` type to `char`, which we can do by means of a cast. `printf("%c", (char)a[0]);`.

Had the array been `char a[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100};` then the cast wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It's not in the correct format, that's what the cast is for. `72` is `0x48000000` while `'H'` is `0x48`.

Comment: @OrangeDog: "*`72` is `0x48000000`*" no, it is not. `0x48000000` is `1207959552‬`, which is not `72`.

Comment: @alk Typo, thanks. I think all of these endianess derailing discussions made my brain change byte order...

Comment: the `"%c"` `printf()` conversion specifier expects a value of `int` type

Comment: @pmg We already went through that discussion in another answer. Yes indeed `%c` must handle an input in `int` format because of default argument promotions. Though formally "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." So always cast to the intended type, consistently. Next time there's another conversion specifier there and the type passed might matter.

Comment: @alk only if you're running on a big-endian system, which is unlikely.

Comment: The correct type for `%c` is `int`. The entry for `c` in C 2018 7.21.6.1 8 says this explicitly: “if no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument…”

Comment: We can also note the difference in phrasing from `hh` in 7.21.6.1 7, which says the specifier “applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing…” Thus, for `%hhd` or `%hhu` etc., we are restricted to passing a value that results from a `signed char` or `unsigned char` if we want defined behavior. For `%c`, this phrasing does not exist; we may pass any `int` value, and it will be converted to an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of structs since the array may contain different data type.
Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct data
{ 
    int j; 
    char c;
};
int main() 
{
    int a[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    struct data value[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>=48 && a[i]<=57)
        {
            char ch= a[i];
            value[i].j =ch; 
        }
        else
        {
            char ch= a[i];
            value[i].c =ch;  
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         if(a[i]>=48 && a[i]<=57)
            printf("%d",value[i].j); 
        printf("%c",value[i].c); 
         }
   return 0;
}
```

Output will be: Hello World
(Hope it helps.)